# Problem in Decimal Value

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

```
private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000000");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str ="73.71" ; 
            BigDecimal decimal= new BigDecimal(str);
            System.out.println("Tesing1 " + decimal.floatValue()/10000);
            System.out.println("Tesing2 " + decimal.floatValue());
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(decimalFormat.format(decimal.doubleValue()/ 10000));
            System.out.println("Tesing3 " + bigDecimal);        
        }
```

In the Above code out put is

Tesing1 0.007371
Tesing2 73.71
Tesing3 0.0073710000

But when i try to save it into database using hibernate its value become as 74. Doing rounding stub.

Does any one know what is reason.

Using this code i am saving the object

```
public boolean save(Object transInstance) {
        boolean lSuccess = false;
        getHibernateTemplate().save(transInstance);
        lSuccess = true;

        return lSuccess;
    }
```

and this is .hbm file entry for that column and column defination in table

```
<property name="actlRsltPt" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ACTL_RSLT_PT" precision="6" scale="4" />
        </property>

ACTL_RSLT_PT NUMBER (6,4)
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table? (and as you have Hibernate the mapping as well)?

Comment: what's your database schema (where you're saving it)? where is your code for writing to the database?

Comment: How do you store the value in the database? And what type has the column?

Comment: And the entity is? And how are you setting the value exactly? And what query is performed? And how did you check the database side?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an issue with Hibernate, check what values for scale and precision and datatype you have in your mappings and in the database itself.

Also, why are you taking a BigDecimal (an arbitrary-precision signed decimal number) and then taking its `float` value to do division? This defeats the purpose of using a BigDecimal and reverts back to floating point math which may lead to unexpected results. You should divide BigDecimal instances with the [`BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)) method (or one of it's overloads).